# Display unique characters only in a textbox

Tags: text, webforms

If I give the input from Text Box like

> AaBbcdCDEb

the output should be

> ABCDE or abcde

only unique characters should be there, no repeated characters.

How do I do this?

Comment: this sort of looks like a homework question.....

Comment: What are you trying to do? Remove duplicates?

Comment: Who care if it's homework or not... this is allowed.

Comment: it's allowed but it can be tagged homework, too

Answer (score 4):

Use the Distinct extention method on the array of characters then recombine them into a string.

```
new string("AaBbcdCDEb".ToLower().Distinct().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "AABBCCDD";
string output = string.empty; 
foreach(char c in input)
    if (!output.Contains(c))
        output += c;
```

Comment: Thank you sir its working fine......but its working only for either uppercase or lower case not both i mean if i give input "AAABBCCDDaabbccdd" the output is coming "ABCDabcd" but output should be either"ABCD" only or "abcd"only but not both.....pls send me sir.

Answer (score 0):

foreach char in textbox, if textbox/new string contains char then return, else add to new string?

Comment: Sir i want to give dynamic input at run time from TextBox.....if the the input is AABBCCDD and if i click one Button the result should be displayed in another TextBox.....Result should be only ABCD.......sir pls send me the entire code.

Comment: FedEx, TNT, UPS what's you favourite?